# Trying to calculate average and St. DEV in VBA but keep getting whole numbers?

Tags: arrays, excel, for-loop, vba

I am trying to write a program that will calculate control limits based on the first 50 values of several columns. DateTime_Column is an Integer and is the last column I need to do the for loop on.

My problem is that the function I am using to calculate the average and st deviation doesn't seem to be working. I am getting whole numbers when I should be getting decimals.

```
    Dim Ave As Long
    Dim STDev As Long
    ReDim UCL(DateTime_Column) As Long
    ReDim LCL(DateTime_Column) As Long
    DateTime_Column As Integer

      DateTime_Column = WorksheetFunction.match("Date_Time", Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)

     For i = 1 To DateTime_Column

     ColLtr = Replace(Cells(1, i).Address(True, False), "$1", "")
     Ave = Application.Average(Range(ColLtr & "1:" & ColLtr & "50"))
     STDev = Application.STDev(Range(ColLtr & "1:" & ColLtr & "50"))
     UCL(i) = Ave + 3 * STDev
     LCL(i) = Ave - 3 * STDev

     Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you declared both `Ave` and `STDev` to be of type `Long`, which is an integer type. If you want them to hold floating point numbers you should declare them to be of type `Double` rather than `Long`.